# does GeoFire support geo queries search for polygons within point, rather than points within polygons?

Tags: firebase, geofire

My query would be to find what neighborhoods(polygons) I'm in or close to.  The geofire examples only show the vice versa, where I'm searching for points within a shape (circle or region).

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc

Does geofire support my use case?

Comment: I don't think geofire natively supports this. But geofire's searching is based on geohashes, so it might be worth a few searches if/how your use-case can be accomplished with just geohashes.

Comment: @monkeyBonkey - Have you found solution? i am also looking for solution.